# AES key wrapping using another AES key and unwrapping to get the original key (RFC 3394 and RFC 5649)

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rfc

I am trying AES key wrapping using another AES key and unwrapping to get the original key *(RFC 3394 and RFC 5649)*. The way of wrapping and unwrapping the key is as follows:

**Key wrapping**

1. Convert into byte[]
2. Wrap using AES

- Get Cipher instance `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`
- Generate IvParameterSpec
- Create a SecretKey object from the wrapper key
  `SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(wrapperKey, "AES");`
- Initialize the cipher for encryption
  `cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, secretKey, iv);`
- Perform wrapping `byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(new SecretKeySpec(keyToWrap, "AES"));`
- return wrapped key

**Key unwrapping**

1. Convert wrapped key to byte[]
2. Unwrap using AES

- Get Cipher instance `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");`
- Extract IV (16 bytes)
- Create a SecretKey object from the wrapper key
  `SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(wrapperKey, "AES");`
- Initialize the cipher for encryption
  `cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, secretKey , iv);`
- Perform unwrapping `Key unwrappedKey = cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);`

**Problem**

The issue I am facing while unwrapping is that I am not getting the original key back and the difference is caused by first 16 bytes in byte array which is the size of IV. I debugged but couldn't find the reason causing this.

Dependencies used

`SunJCE: Cipher.AES -> com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher$General aliases: [Rijndael]`

Below is the output.

1.
Original Key: `00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff`

Original Key in byte[] : `[-45, 77, 117, -37, 109, -9, -29, -114, 121, -21, -82, -5, -13, -49, 125, 105, -90, -37, 113, -57, 93, 121, -25, -33]`

Original IV : `[-76, 50, 106, -33, -77, -80, -90, 53, -11, -91, 17, 25, -21, -63, -57, 17]`

2.

Wrapped Key : `gxLT9+PTn8rikNLJnK1RcpNqFIL/fG7EPLVsIr5mwOA=`

wrapped key in byte[] : `[113, 0, 125, 123, 85, 97, 65, 123, 118, 91, -22, -117, 62, 37, 117, -11, -119, 98, -128, 16, -85, -51, -47, 109, -15, -65, 123, -89, -92, -81, -78, 38]`

IV from wrapped key : `[113, 0, 125, 123, 85, 97, 65, 123, 118, 91, -22, -117, 62, 37, 117, -11]`

3.

Unwrapped Key: `RhzNRM6VgeHUTAkIpYfHnqbbccddeeff`

Unwrapped Key byte[]: `[22, 127, 98, 127, -117, 38, 4, -64, -6, 21, 85, 105, 38, 43, -49, -115, -90, -37, 113, -57, 93, 121, -25, -33]`

=============================================

Diff seems to be due to 16 bytes (the size of IV)

org key : `[-45, 77, 117, -37, 109, -9, -29, -114, 121, -21, -82, -5, -13, -49, 125, 105, -90, -37, 113, -57, 93, 121, -25, -33]`

output key : `[22, 127, 98, 127, -117, 38, 4, -64, -6, 21, 85, 105, 38, 43, -49, -115, -90, -37, 113, -57, 93, 121, -25, -33]`

Adding code :

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class KeyWrapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String originalKeyHex = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff";
        String wrappingKeyHex = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f";

        // converting hex strings to byte arrays
        byte[] originalKey = hexStringToByteArray(originalKeyHex);
        byte[] wrapperKey = hexStringToByteArray(wrappingKeyHex);

        // Encrypt the key
        byte[] wrappedKey = aesKeyWrapEncrypt(originalKey, wrapperKey);

        // Decrypt the key
        byte[] unwrappedKey = aesKeyWrapDecrypt(wrappedKey, wrapperKey);

        // Display results
        System.out.println("Original Key: " + byteArrayToHexString(originalKey));
        System.out.println("Wrapped Key : " + byteArrayToHexString(wrappedKey));
        System.out.println("Unwrapped Key: " + byteArrayToHexString(unwrappedKey));
    }

    // AES Key Wrap Encryption
    private static byte[] aesKeyWrapEncrypt(byte[] keyToWrap, byte[] wrapperKey) throws Exception {
    
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // Generate a random Initialization Vector (IV)
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(ivBytes);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Create a SecretKey object from the wrapper key
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(wrapperKey, "AES");

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, secretKey, iv);


        // Encrypt the key
        byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(new SecretKeySpec(keyToWrap, "AES"));

        return wrappedKey;

    }

    // AES Key Wrap Decryption
    private static byte[] aesKeyWrapDecrypt(byte[] wrappedKey, byte[] wrappingKey) throws Exception {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // Extract the Initialization Vector (IV) from the wrapped key
        byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(wrappedKey, 0, ivBytes, 0, ivBytes.length);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

        // Create a SecretKey object from the wrapping key
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(wrappingKey, "AES");

        // Initialize the cipher for decryption
        cipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, secretKey, iv);

        // Decrypt the key
        Key unwrappedKey = cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);

        return unwrappedKey.getEncoded();
    }



    // Helper method to convert byte array to hex string
    private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] array) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);
    }

    // Helper method to convert hex string to byte array
    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(hexString);
    }
}
```

**Update :**

Thanks @President James K. Polk for pointing out the exact issue. It worked with below fix.

```
    // AES Key Wrap Encryption
    private static byte[] aesKeyWrapEncrypt(byte[] keyToWrap, byte[] wrapperKey) throws Exception {
...

            byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(new SecretKeySpec(keyToWrap, "AES"));
    
            // prepending the IV to the wrapped key
            byte[] result = new byte[ivBytes.length + wrappedKey.length];
            System.arraycopy(ivBytes, 0, result, 0, ivBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(wrappedKey, 0, result, ivBytes.length, wrappedKey.length); 
...
```

Comment: During the wrapping process you don't store the IV anywhere. During unwrapping you assume the 1st 16 bytes of the wrapped key are the IV, but you never put the IV there. And then you attempt to unwrap the same 16 bytes that you've mistakenly assumed were the IV along with the rest of the wrapped key.

Comment: Note that I would much prefer modes like AES-SIV for key wrapping. CBC doesn't provide message integrity nor authentication and should not be used for *sending* keys where a padding oracle could be present. Use cryptography carefully!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for pointing out the issue. I missed storing the IV during wrapping. Fixing it worked. Thanks!!